# How can I scan for only the third octet of an ip?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, ip

I want to be able to scan my companies network for all the cameras that may have been forgotten. I know that the cameras all use the same first, second, and fourth octet but the third changes. Is there a way I can only scan the third octet?

Comment: We'll need more information.  "Scan" how?  Which OS are you scanning from?  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you can do something similar to:

```
for f in `seq 0 255`
do
  $scan X.Y.$f.Z
done
```

Where `$scan` is whatever type of scan you're doing on that specific IP address. Giving more information, as techie007 requested in a comment, will undoubtedly get you better solutions.